# Кавычки в названии маршрутов общественного транспорта

Tags: пунктуация

Согласно справочникам название маршрута с указанием конечных пунктов оформляется через тире и пробелы (Розенталь, Мильчин). При этом названия остановок общественного транспорта заключаются в кавычки. По этой логике маршруты метро, трамваев и пр. нужно оформлять так: *автобусный маршрут №7 "Проспект Парковый" — "Площадь Дружбы"*.
Как вы считаете? Подобное оформление нигде не встречала, чаще вижу *"Проспект Парковый — Площадь Дружбы"*.

Answer (score 1):

Остановка "Проспект Парковый". Автобусный маршрут №7 "Проспект Парковый  — Площадь Дружбы".

Здесь разные родовые названия: остановка, маршрут.

Имя собственное имеет следующую структуру: родовое имя, далее само название, заключенное  кавычки (это название строится по своим правилам и не состоит из названий остановок).

Answer (score 0):

Хороший вопрос...
Понятно, что в названиях маршрутов никто лишних кавычек вам не позволит, просто тогда получилось бы вложенные кавычки, внешние - для названий маршрута, внутренние - для остановок. А это совершенно излишне.

Можно, конечно, понапридумывать отдельных правил под каждую традицию (вон как Sergey предлагает), но мне такое что-то совсем не нравится.

Я просто думаю, что названия конечных пунктов в названии маршрута - это не названия остановок, а обычные конечные пункты. Как в поезде:  ("Москва -- Пекин", хотя на самом деле и тут не города имеются в видк ж/д станции "Москва" и "Пекин".

Такая традиция в общем-то тоже не нова. Вот для аналогии остановка «Стадион "Динамо"» - это в Москве в автобусных маршрутах, но станция метро "Динамо" (тоже по стадиону названная). С потерей родового слова теряются и кавычки.

По-другому я логически объяснить не могу. Интересно, как эта традиция обходится с названиями типа "Красный Октябрь" - здесь кавычки относятся к названию объекта рядом с остановкой. Где-то я такие названия видел...

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Если я правильно Вас поняла, Вы исходите из того, что обозначение маршрута должно заключаться в кавычки. Но у Розенталя, например, указано, что при обозначении пространственных пределов используется длинное тире, и приведен пример поезд Москва - Иркутск. И даже если имеются в виду железнодорожные станции, то и там кавычки не нужны, т.к. названия станций не кавычатся (по Мильчину), в отличие от остановок общественного транспорта.

Comment: Не, не совсем так. . Вы знаете, тут с кавычкам в названиях поездов некоторая неразбериха. Маршрут - именно маршрут - в кавычках не нуждается. "поезд, следующий по маршруту Москва - Иркутск" тлт по-професстональному "сообщением Москва -- Иркутск") ну какие тут еще кавычки-то нужны и зачем?! Когда имеется в виду именно это, сообщение, кавычки не нужны. А когда это становится условным именем собственным поезда, названием его, боюсь, что  без кавычек не обойтись. Об этом прямо у Розенталя не говорится.

Comment: Вот смотрите. *Автобус №17 сообщением МОСКВА - д. ГАДЮКИНО*. Вряд ли кому в голову придет кавычки поставить. Теперь сравним: *Автобус "Канавы Ближние - Овраги Дальние"*. Ну напрашиваются кавычки, это ж не просто названия пунктов, это *всё вместе* "имя" маршрута.

Comment: Я не буду на этих кавычках очень уж сильно настаивать, но в принипе в некоторых случаях они все-таки возможны. В любом случае на дальнейших соображениях это сказывается не очень сильно.